# CSS and Images mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have this page where I want to use mod_rewrite to make rewrites from

`http://example.com/dev/main/1234`

to

`http://example.com/dev/index.php?page=main&id=1234`

I have succesfully got the mod_rewrite working for the page but I still have problems with CSS and images.

```
  1 Options +FollowSymLinks
  2 
  3 ReWriteEngine on
  4 RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /dev/index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
  5 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  6 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

The css is located at /var/www/dev/css and images in /var/www/dev/img. How can I get the mod_rewrite to load the same images and css when I access the http://example.com/dev/main/1234 ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you got those two conditions in your htaccess (I assume your htaccess in in the /dev folder) ?

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

If not, your images url will be rewritten, because they match your regex (css/image.jpg)

Thos two conditions avoid url rewriting when the request is a real path (pointing on a file or an folder)

Comment: I have .htaccess in /dev folder. I added the conditions but it is still not working. When I check out the source and follow the link to css/main.css I am getting an apache 404 error with request to /var/www/dev/main/css/main.css ..

Comment: Keep those conditions anyway. Have you got other rules set ?

Comment: No other rules there. Here is the complete .htaccess:

  1 Options +FollowSymLinks
  2 
  3 ReWriteEngine on
  4 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  5 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  6 RewriteRule ^(.*)/([^/\.]+)/?$ /dev/index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]

Comment: Then you must have a problem in your PHP code, there can't have a `main/` folder which come from nowhere in the url.

Comment: Ow... put the conditions *before* the rule, between `RewriteEngine` line and `RewriteRule` line

Answer (score 0):

Whoa. Got it working with some hacking. Don't know if this is the right way to do it but it works:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/css/(.+)?$ css/$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/img/(.+)?$ img/$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: No answer mainly because your question was not precise enough. For example, my own rewrite rules are base on vhost and on the extension of the file.